# Active directory to store certificate detail

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

My client has come with new requirement to store certificate data inside the AD. 
Currently user are able to login to site using user name and password. New requirement is to authenticate the user by Digital certificate(Certificate provider is Unipass).

In order to make user to login using Digital certs, first user needs to Register with Digital certificate. We have decided to store these Digital certificate in AD. But the question is how. Is there any api or function which Active directory/LDAP provides to store certificate details? or do we have to store these information AD custom attributes?

Please note that, While registering the certificate, we will get the certificate data in Byte64 format.

Your help much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research i found that, there is no inbuilt field in Active directory to store the certificate details.

The better approach would be to store it in Structured data(Data base).